# Andular material datepicker issue with local change-detection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, detection, angular-changedetection

I am having an issue where we need local change-detection for our component, otherwise other aspects are slow as hell.
But this interferes with the mat datepicker overlay.
When we want to move around with arrow-keys inside the overlay. And it changes the month or year you are in, the selection and focus disappears from the overlay.(You were on the last day of current month you press right arrow key, you are on the next month but the overlay loses focus& there's no selection inside the overlay)

I found out when I remove the local change detection it's working as intended, but sadly then our component (mainly a 3rd party map which is required for this component to run becomes too slow, we figured out that this change detection is helping with that, but it messes up the datepicker overlay and we need both).

How can I fix this issue? Any hints/tricks?

I've done a representation of the issue, the change detection is set up in our component similarly. The component itself is pretty big and complex so i've just recreated the issue itself.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9zcdsh?file=src/app/datepicker-events-example.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: link provided by you is working properly.

Comment: you can read about change detection in detail here https://jagjeets.medium.com/using-angular-change-detection-effectively-f69d6a493c35

Answer (score 0):

I've also your link and it works well (used google chrome on windows). Try different browser or operation system. Sometimes 3rd party libraries has issues with supporting diffrent browsers (especially safary). Also I see you use angular 12, I'd recommend to update it. If you need some hacks to overcome change detection issues, the simplest is react to the problemed event (right arrow) and manually call `.detectChanges()` on `ChangeDetectorRef`.